# Db2 error "An expression in the ORDER BY clause .. is not valid." when using LISTAGG(DISTINCT ..)

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

This query seems to be valid in Db2 v11.5.7.0:

```sql
SELECT listagg(DISTINCT x, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x)
FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (2)) t (x)
```

But it fails with:

> SQL Error [42822]: An expression in the ORDER BY clause in the following position, or starting with "" in the "ORDER BY" clause is not valid.  Reason code = "2".. SQLCODE=-214, SQLSTATE=42822, DRIVER=4.29.24

What possible other thing could I use in the `ORDER BY` clause, other than `x` itself? Note that the problem is related to `DISTINCT`. This works:

```sql
SELECT listagg(x, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x)
FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (2)) t (x)
```

And produces the expected output:

> 1,1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behaviour. [According to the docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-listagg):

> If DISTINCT is specified for LISTAGG, the *sort-key* of the ORDER BY specification must match *string-expression* (SQLSTATE 42822). If *string-expression* is implicitly cast, the *sort-key* must explicitly include a corresponding matching cast specification.

So a possible workaround is:

```sql
SELECT listagg(DISTINCT x, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(x as VARCHAR))
FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (2)) t (x)
```

Of course, that ordering might not be the same as the intended one, so this workaround may not apply to all input data!

Comment: You may use DISTINCT in a subselect in a simple case: `SELECT listagg (x, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x)
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT X AS X
FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (2), (11)) t (x)
)`

Comment: The same approach can be used for more complex cases (multiple lists for the same group, for example), but the final [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/sbnc3bOt) doesn't look so cute...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein: Sure, simple queries like these can be transformed differently, but assuming the actual query being much more complex than this minimal example...

Comment: Not sure why, but I get SQL0214N when I try the above query. I needed to cast x in listagg as well: `...listagg(DISTINCT CAST(x as VARCHAR), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(x as VARCHAR)) ...` Tried it on 11.5.7 and 11.5.8. Note sure when it was introduced, but Db2 now contains an CAST operator :: similar to postgres which is a bit shorter and more readable: `... listagg(DISTINCT x::VARCHAR, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x::VARCHAR)...`

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini: Interesting, well Informix also has this cast syntax, that's more likely the source of inspiration here, IMO. I'm using Db2 LUW from docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2. The syntax also works here: https://dbfiddle.uk/xRED-UsK

Comment: @LukasEder, I pulled down an 11.5.8.0 container and there it works, but it does not work when I try on an installed 11.5.8.0 which is weird. I'll do some investigations.

Comment: Also works for a newly created db on installed 11.5.8, but not in a migrated database. I might open a PMR on this.

Comment: @LukasEder, the error seem to appear when one is using STRING_UNITS=CODEUNITS32 `(db2 "UPDATE DB CFG FOR <db> USING STRING_UNITS CODEUNITS32"; db2stop force; db2start; db2 connect to ...)`.